# ERC721 Metadata not passed from NFT minting contract

Tags: json, solidity, ipfs, erc721

I am trying to create a simple ERC721 contract that mints a NFT hard coded into the contract to anyone who sends 100 Wei.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
 
import "https://github.com/nibbstack/erc721/blob/master/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
 
contract myNFT is NFTokenMetadata {

    uint tokenId = 0;

    string[] nfts = ["https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json"];
 
     function mint() public payable {
         require(msg.value == 100, "Send 100 Wei");
         super._mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
         super._setTokenUri(tokenId, nfts[0]);
         tokenId++;
    }
 
}
```

The metadata JSON looks like this:

```
{"name":"No time to explain!","description":"I said there was no time to explain, and I stand by that.","image":"ipfs://bafybeidfjqmasnpu6z7gvn7l6wthdcyzxh5uystkky3xvutddbapchbopi/no-time-to-explain.jpeg"}
```

This metadata JSON works if I pass this uri as an argument through a standard minting call (_to, _tokenId, _uri), but it doesn't work in the above contract and I don't know what's wrong.

I deployed the contract on the Goerli Testnet, but the image is not visible on opensea testnet:

contract:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x6b9c84cb4f900d74b02854fdf8666abf5f68d457

opensea:
https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/unidentified-contract-snzheyndyi

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by "it doesn't work in the above contract"? ... I was able to correctly return the URI of the minted NFT. Do you want to create a public getter for the URI string regardless of token ID?

Comment: @PetrHejda I cannot view the image on opensea testnet using this contract.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. Can you post the contract address, and on which testnet you deployed it?

Comment: @PetrHejda I updated the information in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSea sometimes can't load the NFT metadata instantly I refreshed your metadata now image is also seenable. Check [here](https://testnets.opensea.io/assets/goerli/0x6b9c84cb4f900d74b02854fdf8666abf5f68d457/0).

Also instead;

```
string[] nfts = ["https://ipfs.io/ipfs/bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json"];
```

Using;

```
string[] nfts = ["ipfs://bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json"];
```

Can be better since it is already stored in blockchain.

Because, in case of https://ipfs.io goes down your NFT's metadata won't be accessible.

Comment: Thanks. How did you „refresh the metadata“?

Comment: In OpenSea there is a refresh button to refresh meta data it sometimes need to check blockchain more than one time to get